# Linux Customizable Dialog?

Tags: linux, bash, kde

I'm generally busy with more than one thing to do during the work day.  I'd like an easy to customize dialog box that I can specify at the terminal.

An example, when I'm done with a background copy in a terminal (In X11), I'd like it to pop up with "copy complete".

Something like `cp alpha bravo && foobar "copy complete"`

Has anyone come across something like this?

Comment: Whats about `wish` command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look at the documentation for `cdialog` `dialog` and `kdialog`

Comment: I have used kdialog in this exact fashion, btw. And for user input and further script control.

Comment: Awesome and easy.  kdialog does the trick

Answer (score 2):

In case someone is looking for this functionality for Gnome, there's [Zenity](http://library.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/).

Answer (score 0):

For the matter, in case that you want the old-style command prompt dialog-box prompts like what you get during debian installation, you can try ncurses

Comment: Technically true, but ncurses is just a library that you can use from a C program. It's not something you can invoke from a terminal; you'd need to write a program (probably in C) to use it. A tool like `dialog` is more appropriate here.